# Stream FQL shows blank messages (which are my posts on other's walls) - but only with 1 App

Tags: facebook, stream, facebook-fql

I've been struggling with this one for a few days.

I use a query like this to get my posts on my wall:
select post_id, viewer_id, app_id, source_id, updated_time, created_time, filter_key, attribution, actor_id, target_id, message, attachment, permalink from stream where source_id = 100003203496908 and updated_time >'1362480430'

This is behaving differently, depending on the App ID.  The apps *appear* to have identical settings, and the users appear to have identical permissions.

With the App that is working properly, it returns only my posts on my wall.

With the app that is not working properly, it returns my posts on my wall.  But it also returns some rows that have empty message and permalink, like this:

```
    (
        [post_id] => 100003203496908_367088630074584
        [viewer_id] => 100003203496908
        [app_id] =>
        [source_id] => 100003203496908
        [updated_time] => 1362487503
        [created_time] => 1362487503
        [filter_key] =>
        [attribution] =>
        [actor_id] => 100003203496908
        [target_id] =>
        [message] =>
        [attachment] => Array
            (
                [description] =>
            )

        [permalink] =>
    )
```

From some testing, I've been able to determine that these are posts I have made on others' walls.  Which I don't think should be returned here.  The Post_id also looks to be bogus.

Any ideas?  Where should I look?  Anything with App settings or permissions that would cause something like this in one app but not another?

Comment: I seem to have the same issue, did you ever find a solution?